# "Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout synchronizing machine check over CPUs" Every time I boot from a live USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, 14.10

I have been stuck on this for months. I built a new PC, and every time I try to run Linux off a live USB drive, I get this after picking "Try Ubuntu" in the grub menu.

[image: kernel output screenshot]

Sorry for cutting some of the ends off, but it was the only way to get a readable image.

The error reads:

```
No Caching mode page found
Assuming drive cache: write through
exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen
SError: { RecovData RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt phyint CommWake 10B8B dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStans UnrecFIS DevExch}
failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 2 pio 512 in
res 40/00:00:00:00:00:/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)
status: { DRDY }
Kernel panic -not syncing: Timeout synchronizing machine check over CPUs
Shutting down cpus with NMI
Kernel Offset: 0x1000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: ....
drm_kernel_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
Rebooting in 30 seconds..
```

I have tried everything. Switching distros, using disks and verifying the bootable USB (It works fine on other PCs).

The motherboard is a MSI Z97 MPOWER and the CPU is an i7 4790K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by unplugging all drives and devices from the pc. The problematic device turned out to be the dvd drive. Without it everything works fine :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using different programs to make the Live USB? When I make a Live USB with the Startup Disk Creator application, I usually get this error (which is odd, since it's the default application). But when I make a Live USB with Unetbootin, it almost always works great.

#### EDIT

I just looked up your motherboard. The BIOS has had a bunch of updates over the past few months, which might suggest that there's been some bugs with it. You could try flashing a newer BIOS: http://us.msi.com/support/mb/Z97_MPOWER_MAX_AC.html#down-bios

#### EDIT2

Resetting the BIOS by clearing the CMOS RAM has helped me before; maybe it will help you too. Here's an image showing how to do this that I grabbed from the manual of your motherboard:

[image: msi Z97 MPOWER CMOS Reset]

If that image is hard to read, it's on page 45 (or section 1-31) of the full manual here: http://dl.msi.com/download_files/mnu_exe/E7888v1.0.zip

I'm sure you already know this, but make sure you do this with the computer off and unplugged.

Comment: I have used Startup Disk Creator, Unetbootin, the disk burner and some windows program and they all fail. The usbs/disks work fine on other pcs though. Also this is not faulty hardware because windows 8.1 runs with no problems.

Comment: At least you know that it works on other PC's, so it is not a bad USB drive. I would guess that an option in the BIOS needs to be changed. Have you tried changing some of the BIOS settings?

Comment: Thats what I thought might be wrong but I don't know what settings might be causing the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's a firmware bug. Have you tried flashing a newer BIOS? That might fix it.

Comment: I have tried but I can't figure out how to flash it. I have extracted the file to the root of the USB but the BIOS can't find any bios file. If I save the bios from the mobo to the usb they have different file extensions (The new one is .160 and the old one is .100) It can see the old bios file but not the new one.

Comment: Is the `BIOS Boot Function` enabled in your current BIOS settings? I think that has to be enabled before it can find the BIOS file on the USB drive.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. This really is a weird issue.

Comment: It gets even weirder i probably should have mentioned this before but i had ubuntu working for a few weeks but then the system started to get more and more unstable until it failed to get past grub. I reset cmos but it didn't help. Im going to try again to update the BIOS again and see if that helps

Comment: I finally managed to get the problem solved with my answer above.